# Webcomic, collection of short stories about war between races (humans, aliens)

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens, webcomics

I read this webcomic 5 years ago, and unfortunately web comics are a bit more difficult to find than normal comics.

All I basically remember was a collection of short stories about war between different races - basically it would focus on a soldier for a chapter or two and then switch - a couple pages I remember basically have one of the alien races bragging about how they use ammunition tubes or sticks (basically sticks of solid material that the guns autoloader cuts up into different sizes of bullets that are used in different situations) while the other race (humans or whatever) still uses magazine ammo.

Comment: Asian style or western?

Comment: @Gallifreyan does anybody still do non-manga art anymore? That's not a joke, I'd really like to know.

Comment: @Broklynite  -  what do you mean? There's manhwa (Korean), manhua (Chinese), also some western webcomics (Death Vigil and Sunstone started as webcomics)

Comment: @Gallifreyan seems like these days all I ever see are manga style art, and it's not a style I care for too much. When done well, it can be beautiful, no argument. But just because I like chocolate doesn't mean I can't enjoy vanilla. But all I ever get is chocolate and it bores me.

Comment: @Broklynite  -  I see what you mean. Check out the ones I mentioned, and others by the same author (his wife does pretty cool webcomics too) on DeviantArt.

Comment: It was western and it was pretty well drawn too (also coloured) - kinda dystopian setting